# Load Data JSon in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, json-simple, jsonnode

I'm trying to load the data.json file for a unity project.
I don't know where I went wrong.
I want to be able to load the level: level1, level2
I have tried some other ways but still not working.
Can anyone review and fix the error for me.

I create LoadDataLevel() to handle level and load data
I create LevelLoadData which contains the elements of the level object

This is my C#:

```
public class BaseGameController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Level> levels;
    public TextAsset textAsset;


    public void LoadDataLevel()
    {
        JSONObject jsObj = (JSONObject)JSON.Parse(textAsset.text);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            string key1 ="level"+i;
            var jsonLevelLoad = jsObj[key1].AsObject;
            levels = new List<Level>();
            if (jsonLevelLoad != null)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j < jsonLevelLoad.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (jsonLevelLoad[j] != null)
                    {
                        Level level = new Level();
                        level.LevelHeight = jsonLevelLoad[i][0].AsInt;
                        var Stars = jsonLevelLoad[j][1].AsArray;
                        if (Stars != null && Stars.Count > 0)
                        {
                            for (int k = 0; k < Stars.Count; k++)
                            {
                                if (Stars[k] != null)
                                    level.Stars.Add(Stars[k].AsInt);
                            }
                        }
                        level.levelId = jsonLevelLoad[j][2].AsInt;

                        var Objects = jsonLevelLoad[j][3].AsArray;
                        if (Objects != null && Objects.Count > 0)
                        {
                            for (int h = 1; h < Objects.Count; h++)
                            {
                                Debug.Log(Objects[h]);
                            }
                        }
                        level.LevelTime = jsonLevelLoad[j][4].AsInt;
                        level.LevelWidth = jsonLevelLoad[j][5].AsInt;
                        levels.Add(level);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
[System.Serializable]
public class LevelLoadData
{
    public int LevelHeight;
    public List<int> Stars = new List<int>();
    public int levelId;
    public List<Object> Objects = new List<Object>();
    public int LevelTime;
    public int LevelWidth;
}
```

This is my data.json
It is list object

```
 {
   "level1": {
        "LevelHeight": 320,
        "Stars": [],
      "Objects":[], 
        "LevelID": 85,
        "LevelTime": 90,
        "LevelWidth": 820
    },
   "level2": {
        "LevelHeight": 320,
        "Stars": [],
      "Objects":[],
        "LevelID": 88,
        "LevelTime": 90,
        "LevelWidth": 1170
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having? Have you stepped through the code in the debugger to try and narrow it down?

Answer (score 0):

First of all your loops / indices make not much sense to me.

You are iterating over

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
```

so assuming there are exactly `100` items `levelX` in your json object but you are telling us there are only 2 right now.

And then you try and access

```
level.LevelHeight = jsonLevelLoad[i][0].AsInt;
var Stars = jsonLevelLoad[j][1].AsArray;
etc...
```

which makes no sense since the `jsonLevelLoad` already **is** the element at index `i`. Also the iteration over

```
for (int j = 1; j < jsonLevelLoad.Count; j++)
```

makes no sense since you already try and index the individual fields by hardcoded indices anyway.

So if something it should probably rather simply be

```
level.LevelHeight = jsonLevelLoad[0].AsInt;
var Stars = jsonLevelLoad[1].AsArray;
etc..
```

However I would rather go by he actual names and do

```
level.LevelHeight = jsonLevelLoad["LevelHeight"].AsInt;
var Stars = jsonLevelLoad["Stars"].AsArray;
etc..
```

Then you are also for each iteration creating a new levels list

```
levels = new List<Level>();
```

so you will always at maximum end up with one single level item.

You want to do this only **ONCE**.

So if you really want to go fully "manual" here it should probably rather be e.g.

```
public void LoadDataLevel()
{
    // you want to do this only ONCE
    levels = new List<Level>();

    JSONObject jsObj = (JSONObject)JSON.Parse(textAsset.text);

    // you want to iterate over the actually existing level amount
    for (int i = 1; i <= jsObj.Count; i++)
    {
        var jsonLevelLoad = jsObj["level" + i].AsObject;
        
        // I would not make silent fails for `null` here at all!
        // IF jsonLevelLoad is really `null` now then it is a BUG and we
        // definitely explicitly WANT the exception
        
        Level level = new Level();
        level.LevelHeight = jsonLevelLoad["LevelHeight"].AsInt;
        var stars = jsonLevelLoad["Stars"].AsArray;
        foreach(var star in stars)
        {
            level.Stars.Add(star.AsInt);
        }

        level.levelId = jsonLevelLoad["LevelId"].AsInt;            
        level.LevelTime = jsonLevelLoad["LevelTime"].AsInt;
        level.LevelWidth = jsonLevelLoad["LevelWidth"].AsInt;
        levels.Add(level);
    }
}
```

---

However, in general instead of parsing this all "manually" I would suggest you rather use `Newtonsoft Json.NET` which comes as a [Package](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json@2.0/manual/index.html) via the [Package manager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Packages.html) and is even pre-installed in latest Unity versions.

Then the JSON data structure you have is basically simply a dictionary so you could use

```
[System.Serializable]
public class LevelLoadData
{
    public int LevelHeight;
    public List<int> Stars = new List<int>();
    // NOTE: the field name MUST match with the name in the JSON file
    // otherwise you will have to explicitly use the attribute [JsonPropertyAttribute(string)]
    // and pass in the desired json field name
    public int LevelId;
    // NOTE: see bottom of answer! Unclear what "Object" is and how exactly you want to deserialize these
    public List<Object> Objects = new List<Object>();
    public int LevelTime;
    public int LevelWidth;
} 

var levelDict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, LevelLoadData>>(textAsset.text);
levels = new List<Level>();
foreach(var data in levelDict.Values)
{
    levels.Add(new Level
    {
        LevelHeight = data.LevlHeight,
        Stars = data.Stars,
        // NOTE: see below
        //Objects = ???
        LevelID = data.LevelID,
        LevelTime = data.LevelTime,
        LevelWidth = data.LevelWidth
    });
}
```

---

Note that in both examples I explicitly omitted the `Objects` field.

Why? > Because in case this is a `UnityEnine.Object` it is completely unclear to me what exactly you have standing in your JSON file and how exactly you are going to create these. `UnityEngine.Object` itself is not serializable into JSON since it will only store a reference and not actually perform a deep serialization I guess.

Comment: I understand.  thank you so much <3